# Integrating Constretto 2.0 with Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring, config, configuration-files

I'm trying to use constretto (2.0.4) with Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE.

My applicationContext.xml file:

```
<beans default-lazy-init="true"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:constretto="http://constretto.org/schema/constretto"

xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://constretto.org/schema/constretto http://constretto.org/schema/constretto/constretto-1.2.xsd
">

<constretto:configuration annotation-config="true" property-placeholder="true">
    <constretto:stores>
        <constretto:properties-store>
            <constretto:resource location="file:/data/config/app.properties"/>
        </constretto:properties-store>
    </constretto:stores>
</constretto:configuration>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close"
        lazy-init="false"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.user}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}"
        p:initialSize="5"
        p:maxActive="100"
        p:maxIdle="30"
        p:maxWait="1000"
        p:poolPreparedStatements="true"
        p:defaultAutoCommit="false"
        p:removeAbandoned="true"
        p:removeAbandonedTimeout="60">
</bean>
```

I have the app.properties file in place with all the properties, and looks like it's not loaded at all, with no calls to any class of constretto.

I get the error:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.driver' in string value "${jdbc.driver}"
```

Any idea of why it isn't working? Anybody successful at this integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with Constretto version 2.2